# Doctrine Query Builder Delete Statement

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I am using Symfony2, i must use the Doctrine QueryBuilder ( http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html ) The documentation does not have an example for the delete or update statement.

My entity is :

```
object(stdClass)[417]
public '__CLASS__' => string 'Les\DataBundle\Entity\News' (length=26)
public 'id' => int 1
public 'restoId' => int 1
public 'category' => string 'dessert' (length=7)
public 'text' => string 'jlkdjsalkdj sa' (length=14)
public 'dateCreated' => string 'DateTime' (length=8)
public 'dateModified' => null
```

I am trying to delete a row in the database, but i keep getting the error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 7 near 'News WHERE n.id': Error: Class 'News' is not defined.

My query is :

```php
$newsID =2 ;
$qd = $repository->createQueryBuilder('n');
$qd->delete('n')
   ->where('n.id = :id')
   ->setParameter('id',$newsID);
$query = $qd->getQuery();
$result = $query->getResult();
```

And would the update statement have the same structure?

Comment: Please type `$query` line (`echo $query;`), it's answer or help to answer. I don't know what `query-builder` is, but query is wrong.

Comment: Please post your entity. try to `var_dump($query->getSQL());` and copy and paste the generated SQL in a MySQL tool and see what's wrong with your query

Comment: @Javad i updated the question, with the entity included.

Comment: @CnapoB i included a link to the Query Builder. But i cannot print anything, as symfony wont render the page as long as this error is not corrected!

Comment: From your link `// Example - $qb->delete('User', 'u')`. Try write like this.

Comment: @CnapoB I get the same error : **[Semantical Error] line 0, col 7 near 'News n WHERE': Error: Class 'News' is not defined**.
 Even thought my Entity is named 'News', for example my getRepository function is : $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('LesDataBundle:News');

Comment: Looks like (by cols number) that your line is `DELETE News WHERE n.id = $newsID`.  Try `$query = $em->createQuery('DELETE News WHERE n.id = ' . $newsID ); $result = $query->getResult();`. But what is `$em` I don't know, may be it's `$qd`. Example from 12.2.1.

Comment: @Codious-JR Did you select a right entity repository to run this query on? If you run `php app/console doctrine:schema:validate` does it show any error? Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: Try also `$query = $em->createQuery('DELETE Les\DataBundle\Entity\News n WHERE n.id = ' . $newsID ); $result = $query->getResult();`. This example from 12.4. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#delete-queries

Comment: @CnapoB i did 
            $query = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQuery('SELECT u FROM LesDataBundle\Entity\News u ');
            $result = $query->getResult();
  as the createQuery function exists in the object from 'getManager'.
But it says That **Error: Class 'LesDataBundle\Entity\News' is not defined**

Comment: Doctrine:schema:validate returns 
**[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct**.
But i get this recurring error for sometime now,   [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
  The table with name 'symfony.fos_user' already exists. I donno why  i keep getting this error. The table is created and working fine, i get access to the entity, but this error appears where ever i execute any schema command

Comment: Maybe it's misprint, but Class is `Les\DataBundle\Entity\News` with slashes. I also find similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939112/symfony2-doctrine-custom-repository-class-semantical-error-line-0-col-14-near

Comment: @Codious-JR If you do not have any data in your DB maybe it's better to drop the schema `php app/console doctrine:schema:drop --force` then create the schema again `php app/console doctrine:schema:create`

Comment: @CnapoB Thanks Alot! the link answered the namespace problem the you actually have to refer to the entity as **LesDataBundle:News**. And i figured out the syntax error for the delete statements, i will answer the question

Answer (score 2):

For the delete statement is different from the select, you don't specify the column name for the delete unlike select.

Corrected Code

```
$qd = $repository->createQueryBuilder('n');
$qd->delete()
   ->where('n.id = :id')
   ->setParameter('id',$newsID);
$query = $qd->getQuery();
$result = $query->getResult();
```

Another Format

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createQuery('delete FROM LesDataBundle:News n where n.id = '.$newsID);
$result = $query->getResult();
```

For the Update Statement it is :

```
$qd = $repository->createQueryBuilder('n');
$qd->delete()
$qd->update()
   ->set('n.text' , ':text')
   ->where('n.id = :id')
   ->setParameters( array('id'=> $newsID, 'text' => 'Hello World') );
$query = $qd->getQuery();
$result = $query->getResult();
```