# Doctrine query builder delete "from" without "from" ?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'm using Symfony 2.8. In the function editAction() of Entity "Offerte" I have this code:

```
foreach($offerte->getGallery() as $gallery) {
            dump($gallery);
            if ($gallery->getImageName() == '') {
                dump("io sono dentro if");
                dump($gallery->getId());
                $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
                $qb->delete('ImageOfferte', 'io');
                $qb->from('image_offerte','io');
                $qb->where('io.id = :id');
                $qb->setParameter(':id', $gallery->getId());
                $qb->getQuery()->execute();
                dump($qb->getDQL());
                exit();
            }
}
```

ImageOfferte is another Entity linked via a OneToMany relationship (via $gallery field)

This code return me this error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 7 near 'ImageOfferte': Error: Class
>   'ImageOfferte' is not defined.

Where is my error ? I have found another "question" [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212370/doctrine-query-builder-delete-statement?answertab=active#tab-top) that say that "delete statement is different from the select " but I don't understand how to use my "ImageOfferte" in that answer.

If I use this code all is ok:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('delete FROM AppBundle:ImageOfferte io where io.id = '.$gallery->getId());
$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: In your first example you're just passing the entity class name as an argument, while in your second one, you are using the short syntax `BundleName:EntityName`. Fix that in your code, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should remove the ->from().

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->delete('ImageOfferte', 'io');
$qb->where('io.id = :id');
$qb->setParameter(':id', $gallery->getId());
$qb->getQuery()->execute();
```