# QueryBuilder/Doctrine Select join groupby

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

So recently I have been thinking and can't find a solution yet to this problem since my lack of development with doctrine2 and symfony query builder.

I have 2 tables:
Goals: id,user_id,target_value...
Savings: id,goal_id,amount

And I need to make a select from goals (all the informations in my table are from the goals table, except that I need to make a SUM(amount) from the savings table on each goal, so I can show the user how much did he saved for his goal)

This is the MySQL query:

```
    select 

    admin_goals.created,
    admin_goals.description,
    admin_goals.goal_date,
    admin_goals.value,
    admin_goals.budget_categ,
    sum(admin_savings.value) 

    from admin_goals 
inner join admin_savings on admin_savings.goal_id=admin_goals.id 
    where admin_goals.user_id=1 
    group by admin_goals.id
```

It returns what I want but I have no idea how to implement it with doctrine or query builder, can you please show me an example in both ways?
[image]
I highly appreciate it !
[image]

Comment: You must define your Entity properly. You can follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939112/symfony2-doctrine-custom-repository-class-semantical-error-line-0-col-14-near

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume you need this fields only and not your `AdminGoals` entity. On your `AdminGoalsRepository` you can do something like this:

```
public function getGoalsByUser(User $user) 
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('goal');
    $qb->select('SUM(savings.value) AS savings_value')
       ->addSelect('goal.created')
       ->addSelect('goal.description')
       ->addSelect('goal.goalDate')
       ->addSelect('goal.value')
       ->addSelect('goal.budgetCat') //is this an entity? it will be just an ID
       ->join('goal.adminSavings', 'savings', Join::WITH))
       ->where($qb->expr()->eq('goal.user', ':user'))
       ->groupBy('goal.id')
       ->setParameter('user', $user);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
}
```

Keep in mind that the return object will be an array of rows, each row is an associated array with keys like the mappings above.

### Edit

After updating the question, I am going to change my suggested function but going to leave the above example if other people would like to see the difference.

First things first, since this is a unidirectional ManyToOne between `AdminSavings` and `AdminGoals`, the custom query should be in `AdminSavingsRepository` (*not like above*). Also, since you want an [aggregated field](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html) this will *"break"* some of your data fetching. Try to stay as much OOP when you are not just rendering templates.

```
public function getSavingsByUser(User $user)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('savings');
    //now we can use the expr() function
    $qb->select('SUM(savings.value) AS savings_value')
       ->addSelect('goal.created')
       ->addSelect('goal.description')
       ->addSelect('goal.goalDate')
       ->addSelect('goal.value')
       ->addSelect('goal.budgetCat') //this will be just an ID
       ->join('savings.goal', 'goal', Join::WITH))
       ->where($qb->expr()->eq('goal.user', ':user'))
       ->groupBy('goal.id')
       ->setParameter('user', $user);

       return $qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
}
```

### Bonus

```
public function FooAction($args) 
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $this->getUser();
    //check if user is User etc depends on your config
    ...

    $savings = $em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:AdminSavings')->getSavingsByUser($user);

    foreach($savings as $row) {
        $savings = $row['savings_value'];
        $goalId =  $row['id'];  
        $goalCreated = $row['created'];
        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

Comment: I get an: Attempted to call method "createQueryBuilder" on class "AppBundle\Entity\Goal". Controller: $x=$goal->getGoalsByUser($user); // $goal=new Goal(); ... in I put your function in the Goal Entity, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: As I have said, this has to be on your `AppBundle\Entity\GoalRepository`. If you don't have one, you can [generate](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I finally generated my repository and run the function.. i get an: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 173 near 'savings WHERE': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Goal has no association named adminSavings  .. this basically means that i don't have a adminsavings(this is the sum) field in the table, but i don't want to alter my table structure for goals, what if i want to show 3-4 sums() from other tables, do i need to create a table collumn for each sum() i want to show?

Comment: See updated, `savings_value` crashed with `savings` from join. Also, many of the names here I just thought of from your query. Make sure to write them as you entity properties are named

Comment: What do i have to write on this line ?   ->join('goal.adminSavings', 'savings', Join::WITH))  ?? I dont have admin_savings in goal .. I have goal_id in the savings table.. so many savings are linked to one goal

Comment: Can you update your question with your entities mappings? At least with the parts you're trying to fetch

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.Saving' doesn't exist  .. I have the table name admin_savings and the Entity: Saving ...can I rewrite this option somewhere or do I have to rename my database tables? ... my declration in Saving Entity  is : /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="admin_savings")
 */

Answer (score 0):

If you use createQuery(), then you can do something like this:

```
    $dqlStr = <<<"DSQL"
select 
admin_goals.created,
admin_goals.description,
admin_goals.goal_date,
admin_goals.value,
admin_goals.budget_categ,
sum(admin_savings.value)
from admin_goals 
inner join admin_savings on admin_savings.goal_id=admin_goals.id 
where admin_goals.user_id=1 
group by admin_goals.id
DSQL;

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery($dqlStr);
    $query->getResult();
```

On the other hand, if you would like to use createQueryBuilder(), you can check this link: http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/symfony2-dbal-querybuilder/

Comment: I tried your sollutiuon too but it doesnt work, I initially get a sintax error, no quotes ? Or isn't there a need for them? If i put quotes I get : Attempted to call method "createQuery" on class "Doctrine\DBAL\Connection".
Did you mean to call "createQueryBuilder"?   .... I just want to run a simple query, jeez.. \

Comment: I didn't mean to call createQueryBuilder(). For complex queries, using QueryBuilder can create a mess and you might waste your time. I added '$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();' and updated!

Comment: ok i got it running but i have this error : [Semantical Error] line 0, col 151 near 'admin_goals
inner': Error: Class 'admin_goals' is not defined. .. it appears the error is on the admin_goals inner join.. part

Comment: That is one of the way how people write multi-line string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848945/best-practices-working-with-long-multiline-strings-in-php. One thing you can try is, don't put any space/tab before the lines as I updated!

Comment: It means something is wrong with your raw sql query!

Comment: I had run the same query copy paste in mysql(phpmyadmin) and worked.. but on the page I get that error..

Comment: Dropped a comment under your question, you are not getting admin_goals from Doctrine. You should have something like: 
'from SOMEBundle:Project admin_goals'