# Symfony2 add property to object

Tags: symfony, object, doctrine-orm, repository, entity

this is a question that continues another topic :

[QueryBuilder/Doctrine Select join groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379053/querybuilder-doctrine-select-join-groupby)

Please open it so you can see there the database schema.

My problem is:

I have a goal and a goal has many savings.

That means that if you want to save money for a goal you will add some savings, so the savings are linked to the goal by id.

In that topic someone talked about a unidirectional link between savings and goals, ( I have goal_id in the savings table, but no saving_id in the goal table).

What I want to do is show a table with a Goal information and append to it a collected value(which is not in the database) this value is the sum of all saving values linked to a goal:

ex :

```
  Goals:
  id: 1
  goal name: Goal1
  ....

  Savings:
  id: 1
  amount:10
  goal_id: 1

  id:2
  amount:20
  goal_id: 1
```

When I query the database I will get a table with the goal information and a field Amount Collected: 30 in this case.

I initially managed to make the query to get me this:

```
    select 

    admin_goals.created,
    admin_goals.description,
    admin_goals.goal_date,
    admin_goals.value,
    admin_goals.budget_categ,
    sum(admin_savings.value) 

    from admin_goals 
inner join admin_savings on admin_savings.goal_id=admin_goals.id 
    where admin_goals.user_id=1 
    group by admin_goals.id
```

But I wanted to do the symfony way so I used query builder, made a repository and didn't have the same result.

The only link between Goals and Savings is the goal_id from the Savings table, that means that using query builder I have to start from the Savings table.. because from the Goals table I have no foreign_key for savings.

But now the problem is that because I start from the Savings table, when displaying the Goals I get a empty result, thats because initially there are no Savings for a Goal.

First you create the Goal and then the Savings. But because there is no record in the Savings table(i start from) I don't get nothing from the Goals table because I have a join on these two tables.

```
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('admin_savings');

        $qb->select('SUM(admin_savings.value) AS savingValue')
            ->addSelect('admin_goals.id AS id')
            ->addSelect('admin_goals.created')
            ->addSelect('admin_goals.description')
            ->addSelect('admin_goals.goal_date')
            ->addSelect('admin_goals.value')
            ->addSelect('admin_budget.name') //    daca vrei id atunci pune identity(admin_goals.categ_id)                          admin_budget.name, x.name
            ->join('admin_savings.goal_id', 'admin_goals', Join::WITH)
            ->join('admin_goals.budget_categ', 'admin_budget', Join::WITH) //parametru 2 e numele de referinta in selectul mare ex: admin_budget, putea fi x
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq('admin_goals.user_id', ':user'))
        ->groupBy('admin_goals.id')
        ->setParameter('user', $user);
```

I understand that this is not possible so i tried another approach, why not I query normally the Goals entity because that is what I want to see..

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Goal');
 $goals = $repository->findBy(array('user_id' => $userId));
```

and I made a function in my SavingsRepository :

```
public function getSavingSumByGoal($goalId){

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('saving');

        $qb->select('SUM(saving.value) AS savingValue')
            ->where($qb->expr()->eq('saving.goal_id', ':goal'))
            ->setParameter('goal', $goalId);

        return $qb->getQuery()->getScalarResult();
    }
```

So now I have the Goals entity with all its information, but not the Amount Sum Collected from the Savings, I need to add that somehow to my $goals object. This is in my controller

```
foreach($goals as $goal_item){
            $savingSum=$SavingRepository->getSavingSumByGoal($goal_item->getId());
            if($savingSum){
                $goal_item->savingSum=$savingSum;
            }else{
                $goal_item->savingSum=0.00;
            }
        }
```

`$goal_item->savingSum` is a fictional property, it doesn't exists in the `$goal` object, I made this as an example that I want to insert that savingSum somehow in the `$goal` object.

I don't want to create another field in the entity and set that, because then I would have a empty column in the database, and I don't want that.. I want to keep the structure of my tables and entities, and only add that sum of all savings amount for a goal in the goals table.

But it doens't work.
I was thinking in the foreach in my twig to execute somehow my function, but I don't think that is a good idea.

```
  {% for goal in goals %}
    <tr style="">
       <td>{{ goal.created|date('Y/m/d')  }}</td>
       <td>{{ goal.description|e }}</td>
       <td>{{ goal.value|e }}</td>
       <td>{{ goal.goal_date|date('Y/m/d') }}</td>
       <td>{{ goal.name|e }}</td>
       <td>{{ savingRepo->getSavingSumByGoal(goal.id)|e }} </td>
        </td>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This is a bad practice and it doesn`t work in twig, but I know people used approach in Zend and other frameworks (after you made the foreach() you run a function of your on the current objects(from foreach) id and show something based on that)

If you have better ideas on how to do this the symfony way .. I can always run the rawquery and it would work, but that is not that I want to do.. there must be a way to do this in a OOP way..please help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't want to create another field in the entity and set that, because then I would have a empty column in the database

You don't have to map a field to database, it can be normal class field